# Are hidden partitions in Windows invisible only in the OS in which they are first designated as such?

Tags: hard-drive

Let's say I hide a partition of an external hard drive on a Windows 8-laptop. Will the hidden partition be visible if the HDD is connected to a different computer running Windows?

In other words, does the hiding only work on the machine on which it is first done, or does the partition retain the property "hidden" when connected to other computers?

**UPDATE#1:**
My question is about visibility within Windows explorer. The partition will be hidden using Windows' Disk Management Tool (removing drive letter).

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Boot the computer with a Live version of Linux or Partition Magic and see for yourself.

You do not define how or what creates the "hidden" partition, so it is hard to know the answer in your case.

Update:

You do not define "other computers".  If you mean another Windows 8 Computer, that would help, and perhaps someone could answer that narrow definition.  "other computers" can mean other versions of windows, Linux even DOS or any operating system that utilizes the disk partitioning scheme.  The all have utilities to view and modify the partition table, and depending on how the "hidden" partition is setup, it might be visible or perhaps not.

It is possible in *nix to write to the raw disk outside of the currently defined partitions and one could create a "hidden" partition/filesystem in the unused portion.  Some (older) copy protection schemes have utilized this method to "ID" a hard drive, so a "copy" of their software runs only on their drives.

If this is a question of will another copy of windows 8 be unable to see a hidden partition created by another windows 8, then the question should be who?  I know some ten year olds who could figure this one out...

YMMV.

Comment: Thanks Timbo. I already knew that, and it's not what I had in mind. Perhaps I could have been more specific.

My question is about visibility within Windows explorer. The partition will be hidden using Windows' Disk Management Tool.

Comment: Partition Magic is very much of the past. I did once try an edition of PM (maybe 8) and it couldn't do what I wanted as PM  was old.  Wikipedia states "As of December 8, 2009, the Symantec website stated that they no longer offer Partition Magic" and "As of October 13, 2011, the Symantec website states, "Sorry, we no longer offer Norton Partition Magic."   The programs people use now are e.g. Easeus's and Paragon's.

Comment: I did define "other computers".

"Will the hidden partition be visible if the HDD is connected to a different computer running WINDOWS?" [emphasis added].

Comment: Also the "who" shouldn't matter since we are only dealing with visibility within Windows explorer, unless you have in mind a way of setting up Windows to display hidden drives within Explorer (what emk referred to).

Comment: Re: partition magic, you are probably correct.  I use Gparted on a dedicated boot disk, and like I still call copiers, Xerox machines, I referred to Gparted as Partition Magic.  Same stuff really, but Gparted is way better.  My apologies for missing the "running windows" part.  Although I am still unsure about "who" would be able to unhide the hidden partition. IIRC, a while back, MS made it impossible to mount the filesystem from one machine on a different machine, in an attempt to prevent someone from seeing protected files.  That went away when you could mount NTFS in Linux.

Answer (score 0):

The hidden property is part of the partition table, so a similar set up with Windows sees the disk as hidden.

The problem is that the other system could well be set up in a way that hidden partitions are visible. If you start disk manager, you'll see all partitions - also the hidden ones.

Comment: Thanks emk.

How can Windows be set up so that hidden partitions show in Windows explorer?